# Total Distinct Formula from current date

Tags: mdx

Please see below the following example:
Contract:   Type of Contract:   End Date:
Yamaha      Active              01/01/2019
Suzuki      Active              01/01/2014
Nissan      Active              01/01/2018
Opel        Disabled            01/01/2020
Mercedes    Disabled             01/01/2013

Totals (distinct count) of the contracts that are marked as Active in the column Type of contract and have the column End Date showing a date greater than the current day. Hence, if the date today is 01/01/2017 the total distinct count should be 2 (Yamaha and Nissan). 
Could you help in providing the correct MDX formula? 
Thanks, 
Shai

Answer (score 1):

We don't see your cube structure to suggest something certain. There is no two or more contracts to see the different between regular one and distinct count from your example. Let's say you have Contract dimension with attributes (Contract,Type of Contract, End Date).

1. Set the value to your Contract attribute in YYYYMMDD format.
2. Add a calculated measure with the following MDX:

> ```
> SUM(
>     existing [Contract].[Type of Contract].&[Active] * [Contract].[End Date].[End Date].Members,
>     IIF(
>         [Contract].[End Date].CurrentMember.MemberValue > Format(Now(),'yyyyMMdd'),
>         1,
>         NULL
>     )
> )
> ```

If you need a distinct count of contractor name you may apply the same logic.